# Is it possible to control the hookblade "catch" when falling?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In previous AC installments, you could voluntarily fall when hanging - and then press a key to grab at a lower point.  AC Revelations seems much the same, except that my hookblade keeps "catching" on things as I fall.  This makes the process of descending a tall building take much longer than previous games.  Can it be avoided, or is it just a nuance of this version?

Comment: It should be exactly the same. As long as you're not pressing the Off Hand button, you should be able to fall freely.

Comment: That is not what happens for me.  I am playing on PC, for the record.  I press shift to hang down from a ledge, press shift again to let go - and intermittently he will grab on with the hookblade, while I am pressing no key.

Comment: How long are you pressing shift? You only need to tap it. If at any point in the fall the game detects you are pressing it, you will grab onto the next available grabable surface. So if you are holding it for too long, it will do as you are describing. Could it be that your shift key is sticking? You could try binding to a different key and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I suppose it's possible my shift key is sticking, but my keyboard is fairly pristine.  I'll check to see if the same key was bound to shift in AC:BH - because I never had the problem with that game.  I am only "tapping" the key, as soon as I begin to fall I let go.

Comment: pressing and holding B lets you freefall without catching.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably doing it wrong.

> You have to press (and keep pressed) the button to fall. In order to
>   control you need to let go of the button so the hook-blade latches on
>   to whatever you're climbing (if it is possible to climb there).